# How to use one column in two detail sections with Crystal Reports

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I need to show one column which is from backend in two detail sections based on the condition that in one detail section this column value should be the second columns(particular) corresponding value and in other detail section except that particular value.
So my question is how to write two different formulas for a single field?

Eg: {abc} = "xyz" in one detail section and
    {abc} <> "xyz" in other detail section

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand *exactly* what you want it to do, but I recommend you start by making 2 new formulas (one for each detail section). Your formulas would look something like this:

> If {abc} = "xyz" then {Somefield}

and

> If {abc} <> "xyz" then {Somefield}